# NullReferenceException while using linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, exception

The following line of code throws NullReferenceException error When I check some checkboxes from the interface, but when I check all the checkboxes the exception won't occur. Each checkbox checked will cause an object to be created, and the objects are stored in an array of the same class.

```
someObjects.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.numericProperty);
```

The array - someObjects - contains some selected objects from some of the checked checkboxes which I want to sort. The array someObjects is also of the same type with the objects. Please how do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Really unintelligible. Objects from checkboxes? How?

Comment: @henk, Each checkbox stands for an object so if any is checked, I create the object. Really unintelligible???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it sounds like `someObjects` contains some null references.

It's probably best to just filter them out:

```
var query = someObjects.Where(obj => obj != null)
                       .OrderByDescending(obj => obj.numericProperty);
```

Or alternatively, just avoid putting them in the array to start with. It's not really clear how the array's being built, but is it *useful* to you to have null references in there?